# Difference between file path and file stream?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

in silverlight , user gets the file stream and not the file path... 
Please can u tell the difference between the two and is there any way to find out file path in silverlight?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlighthosting/thread/bcd26637-3308-4d29-ac25-e1b367f33a2f/

Answer (score 2):

A stream is a pipe to the data, and a path is a *string*... you might be able to get the path from `.Name` if you actually have a `FileStream`, but if you have a `Stream`: not so much.

Comment: is there any way to retrieve the file path ?? i tried to get the isolated storage path in silverlight, but was not able to do so

Comment: @user2091061 that depends a lot on the context and what **exactly** you are being supplied with. What is the `.GetType().FullName` on the object you have access to?

Answer (score 0):

Stream is a pipeline which is plugged to the source and File Path is just a string which is different in differnt OS.

Comment: is there any way to retrieve the file path ?? i tried to get the isolated storage path in silverlight, but was not able to do so.